# Solve $0=f'(x)-cf(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-pde

I have the following problem:

I have a second-order linear ODE
$$\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2a^2f''(x)+\mu a \cdot f'(x)-\rho f(x)=0$$
My exercise is to show that 
$$f(x)=c_1\left(x\frac{\rho}{\gamma}+c_2 \right)^\gamma, \qquad \text{where }\gamma:=\frac{2\sigma^2\rho}{\mu^2+2\sigma^2\rho}.$$

My steps: First, I've found the interior maximizer for $a$, i.e.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2a^2f''(x)+\mu af'(x)-\rho f(x)\right)=\sigma^2\cdot a\cdot f''(x)+\mu f'(x)=0 \Longleftrightarrow a=-\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}\frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)}.$$

Next, I put the maximizer into the linear ODE and get
\begin{align*}
0 &= \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2a^2f''(x)+\mu a \cdot f'(x)-\rho f(x) &\Leftrightarrow\\
\rho f(x) &=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2}\frac{[f'(x)]^2}{f''(x)}-\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2}\frac{[f'(x)]^2}{f''(x)} &\Leftrightarrow\\
\rho f(x) &= -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2}\frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)}\cdot f'(x) &\Leftrightarrow\\
-\frac{2\rho\sigma^2}{\mu^2} &= \frac{f'(x)\cdot f'(x)}{f''(x)\cdot f(x)}
\end{align*}
How can I find the general solution of $f(x)$?

**EDIT:**

By using the rules of logarithm, I get:
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=[\ln(f(x))]'\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)}=c\Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{c}=\ln[f'(x)]'\Leftrightarrow c = \frac{1}{\ln[f'(x)]'}.$$
Then, since $x\in[0,1]$, I get
\begin{align*}
-\frac{2\rho\sigma^2}{\mu^2} &= \frac{\ln(f(x)'}{\ln(f'(x))'} &\Leftrightarrow\\
-\frac{2\rho\sigma^2}{\mu^2} &= [\ln(f(x))-\ln(f'(x))]' &\Leftrightarrow\\
-\frac{2\rho\sigma^2}{\mu^2}\int_0^1 dx &= \ln(f(x))-\ln(f'(x))  &\Leftrightarrow\\
-\frac{2\rho\sigma^2}{\mu^2} &=\ln\left(\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\right).
\end{align*}
Let $\delta:=\frac{2\rho\sigma^2}{\mu^2}$ be defined. Then, by using exponential's rule we get
\begin{align*}
\exp(-\delta) &= \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} &\Leftrightarrow\\
f'(x)-\exp(\delta)f(x)=0.
\end{align*}
Now I have a stupid question: How can I solve it?

Comment: The ODE you can solveby using Laplace transform.

Comment: The important thing to realise is $\partial_x \ln(f(x)) = \frac{\partial_x f(x)}{f(x)}$, provided everything exists.

Comment: Why don't you just plug in $f$, $f'$, and $f''$ in the ODE to verify that $f$ is a solution?

Comment: Why on earth do you believe that $f(x)=c_1\left(x\frac{\rho}{\gamma}+c_2\right)^\gamma$ satisfies the ODE??  Solutions to the ODE are of the form $e^{rx}$ where $r$ is a root of the quadratic equation $\frac12 \sigma^2a^2r^2+\mu at-\rho=0$.

Answer (score 2):

we have $$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx$$ the soltion is $$\ln(|f(x)|)+C$$ if $f(x)\ne 0$ for all real $x$